# how to get gridview value into a dropdownlist

Tags: c#, gridview, drop-down-menu

I am working on a project in asp.net c#. i want to retrieve the `GridView` value/data into `TextBox` and `DropdownList` and perform an update. it seems to work for the `TextBox` but the `DropdownList` seems not to work. please any help.

```
 txtempcode.Text = GridView1.SelectedRow.Cells[1].Text.Replace("&nbsp;", "");
 dropdownlistgend.Text = GridView1.SelectedRow.Cells[2].Text.ToString();
```

Answer (score 2):

You probably need to add `ListItem` to DropDownList instead of changing `Text` property.

```
string gridValue = GridView1.SelectedRow.Cells[2].Text.ToString();
DropDownList1.Items.Insert(0, new ListItem(gridValue, gridValue));
```

Comment: i tried your codes but still not working for me. can you please explain how your codes work?

Comment: This adds list item to dropdown, can you debug the code?

Answer (score 0):

Try This may be help full.

```
DropDownList1.Items.Insert(0, new ListItem(GridView1.SelectedRow.Cells[2].Text.ToString(), GridView1.SelectedRow.Cells[2].Text.ToString()));
```